# How do I send a checkout.customer.double_opt_in_registration instead of checkout.customer.register

Tags: shopware6

When I in my plugin call
$this->customerRepository->create([$someArrayData],$context);

I want shopware to send
**checkout.customer.double_opt_in_registration** event
instead of
**checkout.customer.register** event

I tried every combination of

```
[
    'doubleOptInRegistration' => true,
    'doubleOptInEmailSentDate' => null,
    'doubleOptInConfirmDate'   => null,
    'active'                   => false,
]
```

I also went to Setting->Log-in / sign-up
and enabled **"Double opt-in on sign-up"**

What am I missing?